# Why are people so strongly opposed to #region tags in methods?

Tags: c#, coding-style

I hear a lot about keeping methods short and I've heard a lot of programmers say that using #region tags within a method is a sure sign that it is too long and should be refactored into multiple methods. However, it seems to me that there are many cases where separating code with #region tags within a method is the superior solution to refactoring into multiple methods.

Suppose we have a method whose computation can be separated into three rather distinct phases.  Furthermore, each of these stages is only relevant to the computation for *this* method, and so extracting them into new methods gains us no code reuse. What, then, are the benefits of extracting each phase into it's own method? As far as I can tell, all we gain is some readability and a separate variable scope for each phase (which will help prevent modifications of a particular phase from accidentally breaking another phase).

However, both of these can be achieved without extracting each phase into its own method. Region tags allow us to collapse the code into a form which is just as readable (with the added benefit that we no longer have to leave our place in this file should we decide to expand and examine the code), and simply wrapping each phase in `{}` creates its own scope to work with.

The benefit to doing it this way is that we don't pollute the class level scope with three methods which are actually only relevant to the inner workings of a fourth method. Immediately refactoring a long method into a series of short methods seems to me to be the code-reuse equivalent to premature optimization; you are introducing extra complexity in order to address a problem which in many cases never arises. You can always extract one of the phases into its own method later should the opportunity for code reuse arise.

Thoughts?

Comment: I am currently working with a class that is fairly large. It follows the Single Responsibility Principle; everything in the class is required functionality. It has a lot of private methods, mostly due to refactoring. I use #region to divide these methods into functional categories, which has worked out very well for us. There are many other classes in this project that did *not* require such treatment. The right tool for the right job, I say.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, using them in a class is different than using them inside a method.

Comment: @Chad: Ah, didn't notice that.  Using them in a method does seem a bit extreme. If a method is so long that it requires #regions, I refactor it into separate methods.

Comment: Not really an answer, but not only do I hate all `#region` tags, I turn off code folding in Visual Studio altogether.  I don't like code that tries to hide from me.

Comment: For those stuck in a #region-happy shop, you can assign [this macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523220/awesome-visual-studio-macros/1545900#1545900) to a keyboard shortcut to collapse-to-definitions but expand regions.  (Alas, it'll also expand methods that contain regions.)

Comment: @RobertHarvey are you sure that each of your regions couldn't be extracted as a separate class?

Comment: @jk. The separate classes would be tightly-coupled to each other, and none of the classes could be used on their own to do anything else.  I'd have to pass around tons of parameters.  I think it would be a mess.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I think your last comment captured the general thrust of my idea on this. If none of those classes could be used anywhere else, then having them as separate classes isn't helpful. I think the same is true of methods; if none of those code chunks can be used any where else, then the benefits of having them as a separate method are rather dubious.

Comment: "Furthermore, each of these stages is only relevant to the computation for this method, and so extracting them into new methods gains us no code reuse". OTOH, I find that if I split a function into 3, I often find later that the individual parts <i>are</i> useful later, eg. if some input data changes only one phase, you can test that in isolation, etc.

Comment: I generally dislike regions. A lot. However, I've started using them recently inside methods for tracing/logging. We do a LOT of logging in our current project (a single file is about 40% logging). This makes code quite difficult to read for me (who is more focused on the 'logic' part) -- so I hide away the tracing code in a #region Diagnostics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are #regions an antipattern or code smell?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/53086/are-regions-an-antipattern-or-code-smell)

Comment: [Related](http://staticola.com/Blog#on_code_regions)

Comment: many things in an IDE make you write good code. #region is the opposite.You have to be careful that you are writing good code while using them. For example, it is tempting to make a method longer (instead of breaking the code out into multiple private methods), when you have region tags to hide a lot of the code... since it doesn't look so unweildly anymore. Another problem is... it hides code) that's its purpose. But again you have to pay more attention because of this, otherwise you might miss something that is hidden in there. That said, I use them... why? I like them.. why? I don't know...

Comment: Even after all these years, I fail to understand why everyone is so focused on the ability to *hide* / *collapse* regions in the IDE when discussing regions. To me, this has at best always seemed like an optional gimmick, the true core of regions being more along the lines of having a counterpart to comments for which the compiler enforces the presence of a corresponding closing tag for each opening tag.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

All you should ever care about is for your code to be usable, not reusable. A monkey can transform usable code to reusable code, if there are any transformations to be done at all.

The argument "I need this only here" is poor, to put it politely. The technique you're describing is often referred to as the [headlines technique](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HeadlinesTechnique) and is generally frowned upon.

1. You can't test regions, but you can test true methods in isolation.
2. Regions are comments, not syntactic elements. In the worst case the nesting of your regions and your blocks contradict each other. You should always strive to represent the semantics of your structure with the syntactic elements of the language you are using.
3. After refactoring to methods, one no longer needs folding to read the text. One might be looking at source code in any tool that doesn't have folding, like a terminal, a mail client, a web-view for your VCS or a diff-viewer.
4. After refactoring to methods, the resulting method is at least as good as with regions, plus it is simpler to move the individual parts around.
5. The Single Responsibility Principle suggests that any unit should have one task and one task only. The task of the "main" method is to compose the "helper" methods to get the desired result. The "helper" methods solve a discrete, simple problem in isolation. The class containing all these methods should also only fulfill one task and only contain the methods related to that task. So the helper methods either belong into the class scope, or the code shouldn't be in the class in the first place, but at least in some global method or, better yet, should be [injected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Also relevant: [Jeff Atwoods's thoughts on code folding](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-code-folding/)

Comment: 1. Most programmers don't test all private methods. 2. A method name can't convey every thing there is to know about that method; what exceptions might be thrown? Is null a valid input? Sometimes it's OK to use non-syntactic constructs to make your code more understandable. In many languages, files are an example of a non-syntactic element that is fairly widely accepted as a means for organizing code. 3. Diving into the inner-workings of a method is best attempted in an IDE for a variety of reasons; situations where regions could bite you in your VCS or mail client are rather rare.

Comment: 4. But you've just exported some serious complexity into the rest of your class. Is that worth it? Also, regions can be moved around as easily as a method call. 5. Now your talking about polluting your namespace with more classes which are only going to be used in a single place. Why are classes and methods the only units of encapsulation that you will accept? You can always create that new class later when (or if) it becomes necessary to have this separate.

Comment: @jjoelson: 1. [So what?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_populum) 2. Exactly my point: it is ok to use non-syntactic constructs if (and only if) syntax alone is not enough. 3. "Rare?" - I suppose you have numbers to show that. I can tell you for sure that the diff (or blame or whatever for that matter) tool bundled with TortoiseSVN doesn't have folding. 4. How is that related to the point I made. 5. That is why most modern languages have nestable namespaces. You are resorting to ASCII art rather than using a broad palette of available language elements to structure your code.

Comment: @jjoelson 1) Most programmers I know don't unit test anything.  That doesn't make it correct because it is common.  2) Agreed, however is a region an appropriate construct when a code comment can suffice?  3) I agree with this.  4) Again, if this is a problem then your class is doing too much.  5) If that is your argument then why pollute your namespace with classes at all?  We can all go back to the good old days of top-down functional programming before that meddlesome and complicated OOP started polluting the namespace.

Comment: @back2dos LOL we both wrote almost the exact same thing at the exact same time.  Scary... :)

Comment: 1) Testing private methods is a huge time sink that yields very little benefit, and is especially dubious for a method that is only called in a single location. 2) The corresponding syntax to the region in this case is a nested method (ala Pascal). In C# we can to anonymous delegates which comes close, I guess. I would prefer inner anonymous delegates to splitting up the code into multiple methods when it's only being used in this one place. 3) Why are you looking at an individual method's implementation in Tortoise? You should expect to have a harder time than if you use an IDE.

Comment: 4) It's relevant because the benefit is very tiny compared to the cost, and it can be achieved using regions without incurring that cost. 5) There is no great construct in C# for expressing the idea of a nested method. As I said, anonymous delegates come close, I guess. [EDIT] I should say I'm responding to back2dos.

Comment: @jjoelson: 1. That is your opinion and out of the scope of this question. 2. By extension of my argument nested functions are better than regions, yes. 3. Because I sometimes need to browse through a number of revisions to track a problem. Either way, source code is written for humans, not IDEs. 4. For one the argument is unrelated to my point, secondly that is yet again just your opinion, thirdly it's out of the scope of this question. 5. C# has other means of structuring code than nesting function. You should either use those, or a language that allows nesting functions.

Comment: You guys should take this to chat if you still wish to debate... I have nothing left worth saying to the OP, he is a typical opinionated junior developer set in his beliefs.  Nothing will change his mind but more experience IMO.

Comment: And thus spoke the old, wise @maple_shaft :P

Comment: As for Jeff Atwood's comment's, I agree code folding as a way of organizing is not good if your whole team is not on the same page. However, I disagree with his general aversion to relying on the editor in such a way. When we're talking about C# Windows programming, Visual Studio is a very standard tool that allows us to write code at an even higher level than C#. The fact that regions, XML comments, or any other fluff that Visual Studio allows us to do is not supported by the C# language itself is hardly reason to avoid it. If your entire team is using Visual Studio, then where's the problem?

Comment: @maple_shaft: I'm far from set in my beliefs. Believe me, I don't spend a significant portion of my free time reading books and blogs by expert programmers because I only want my ideas confirmed. I've just never been convinced that there are no situations in which a long method with many parts is preferable to one that has been split up into multiple methods, and none of these answers have convinced me yet.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it seems to summarize most of the reasons people have for extracting such code chunks into helper methods. However, I'm still not convinced that this is always the better solution.

Comment: @jjoelson: Well, your question was "Why are people so strongly opposed to #region tags in methods?" and not "Are they always right?" ;)

Comment: Well played, back2dos.

Answer (score 16):

It's not the regions in the methods that are the problem, but the case when there's a need (or even a use) to put regions in methods.

Having had to debug plenty of 200-300 line methods, I can tell you that I wouldn't wish it on anyone. If you're writing and looking after your own code that's fine - do whatever you want. But once someone else looks at it, it should be immediately clear what a method is doing.

> "First it gets the things, and then it jigs them around, then if they need buzzing it does that, otherwise it checks whether they are blue and inverts their Copernicus value. Then, if the second thing is greater than the first thing, we need to get the juice box and insert it... "

No, that is not good enough. Break it up into regions all you want but I'm still shaking my head just thinking about it.

If you break into methods you get many benefits:

- Clearer understanding of what's happening where, even if just through the name of the method. And you are **wrong** that a method can't be fully documented - add the documentation block (hit `///`) and enter the description, parameters, return type, and also `exception`, `example`, `remarks` nodes to detail those scenarios. That's where it goes, that's what it's for!
- There are no side effects or scoping problems. You may say that you declare all your variables in a sub-scope with `{}`, but do I have to check every method to make sure you didn't 'cheat'? Is this `dodgyObject` I'm using here only because used in this region, or did it come from somewhere else? If I were in my own method I'd be easily able to see whether it was passed to me or whether I created it myself (or rather, whether you created it).
- My event log tells me which method an exception occurred in. Yes, I may be able to find the offending code with a line number, but knowing the method name (especially if I've named them properly) gives me a very good indication of what happened and what went wrong. "Oh, the `TurnThingsUpsideDown` method failed - it's probably failing while turning a bad thing" is a lot better than "Oh, the `DoEverything` method failed - it could have been 50 different things and I'll have to dig around for an hour to find it".

This is all before any reusability or improvability concerns. Properly separated methods obviously facilitate reuse, and also allow you to easily replace a method that's not performing (too slow, too buggy, changed dependency etc). Have you ever tried refactoring any of these huge methods? There's no way to know that what you're changing won't effect anything else.

Please properly encapsulate your logic into reasonably sized methods. I know that it's easy for them to get out of hand, and arguing that it's not worth redesigning once at that point is another issue. But you must accept the fact that there is no harm and at least *potential* benefit in having properly encapsulated, cleanly written and simply designed methods.

Comment: Visual Studio's XML comment parsing, along with the #region tags, falls under the category of Visual Studio features. My whole point is that it's not wrong to rely on these features if everyone in your project is using Visual Studio. As for side effect and scoping problems, you can still screw things up with global fields. In either case you must rely on the programmers not to do silly things with side effects.

Comment: @jjoelson You can still read the XML comments without visual studio, but the region tags are almost completely useless outside VS. The logical extension of your argument is one giant method that runs your entire application is okay, as long as you have it separated into regions!

Comment: @jjoelson please don't get us started on how bad global fields are. Saying something is not useful because you have a "workaround" to screw it up anyway is just silly. Just keep you methods short and variables scoped.

Comment: @OliverS, Kirk was the one who brought up shared state as a problem  with my regions-in-a-method scheme. Basically, I was saying exactly what *you* are saying: the fact that a programmer could abuse state by sharing too many variables between regions is not an indictment of the entire scheme, just as the ability to screw up state shared between methods via globals isn't an indictment of the multiple-method scheme.

Answer (score 8):

If your method is complex enough that it can be separated into three distinct phases, then not only should those be three separate methods...but your method should in fact be a separate class, dedicated to that computation.

"But then my class will have only one public method!"

You're right, and there's nothing wrong with that.  The idea of the single responsibility principle is that your class does **one thing**.

Your class can call each of the three methods in turn, and return the result.  One thing.

As a bonus, now your method is testable because it's not a private method anymore.

But never mind **one** class; in reality you should have **four**: One for each of the pieces of your method, plus one that takes each of the three as a dependency and calls them in the proper order, returning the result.

This makes your classes even *more* testable.  It also makes it easy for you to change one of those three pieces.  Just write a new class inheriting from the old one, and override the changed behavior.  Or create an interface for the behavior of each of your three pieces; and then to replace one, just write a new class implementing that interface and substitute it for the old one in your dependency injection container configuration.

What?  You're not using dependency injection?  Well, you probably haven't seen the need yet, because you're not following the single responsibility principle.  Once you start, you'll find that the easiest way to give each class its dependencies is to use a DI container.

**EDIT**:

OK, let's set aside the refactoring question.  [The purpose of `#region` is to hide code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755465/do-you-say-no-to-c-sharp-regions/1235546#1235546), which mainly means code that doesn't need to be edited under any normal circumstances.  **Generated code** is the best example.  It should be hidden in regions because ordinarily you don't need to edit it.  If you do need to, then the act of expanding a region gives you a bit of "Here be dragons"-style warning to make sure you know what you're doing.

Therefore I would say `#region` should *not* be used in the middle of a method.  If I open a method, I want to see the code.  Using #region gives me another level of hiding that I don't need, and that becomes an annoyance: I unfold the method...and still can't see any code.

If you're worried about people seeing the structure of the method (and you refuse to refactor it), then add banner comments like this:

```
//
// ---------- COMPUTE SOMETHING OR OTHER ----------
//
```

These will help someone browsing the code see the individual parts of your method without having to deal with expanding and collapsing `#region` tags.

Comment: All of this for a method which gets called in *one* place? Even most hardcore Lispers won't abstract out a higher order function until they've identified at least two places where it can be used to more easily define a function.

Comment: @jjoelson Is it so hard to make a new class? What is it, one line, one opening brace and one closing brace. Oh, and you have to press `ctrl+n`

Comment: It's not that it's difficult to *make* a new class, but there is some overhead to *having* an extra class. It's one more layer of indirection which makes it more difficult for a code maintainer to find what she's looking for. It's not *that* big of a deal, but it also doesn't buy you anything in the case where this bit of code is unlikely to be called from anywhere else. And, as you mentioned, it is quite easy to make that new class and put the code there if it turns out you *do* need to call this bit of code in multiple places.

Comment: @jjoelson, this is a pretty common reaction.  It was mine, when I first learned about things like SRP and DI, and it was my co-workers' reaction when we started breaking out dependencies.  If you're looking at *one individual case*, it doesn't seem worth it.  The benefit is in the aggregate.  Once you start doing SRP with *all* your classes, you find that it's far easier to change a piece of your code without the changes rippling through half your application.

Comment: @Kyralessa, these are methods that are only used in a single place. Changing such a method won't ripple through half your application. If such code is implemented as a region in the method that uses it, then you have perfect encapsulation; *only the containing method* is using the code and so you're free to change it all you want without worrying about the effect of it except in that method.

Comment: @jjoelson, you've said that a good dozen times already.  Now let me ask you something: Why did you ask a question on this board if you don't want an answer?

Comment: @Kyralessa, I do want answers. Unit testing, debugging (stack traces, stepping through code, etc.) were all great points raised in other answers. This whole question is about whether or not "helper  methods" should be extracted for code chunks that are only used in a single place, and your answer is all about making flexible interfaces. I don't deny the wisdom of a flexible interface for many cases, but I think creating a complicated interface for a method which gets used in one place is a waste of time, hurts readability, and helps nothing. Am I not allowed to disagree with your answer?

Comment: @jjoelson, sure, you can disagree with any answer.  But you look to have disagreed with *every* answer, which naturally makes us all wonder just what you're really looking for.  You don't need anyone's permission to code the way you want to.  If *all* of us are somehow missing the point of your question, then you might consider editing your question to make the point clearer.  (If you're just looking for people to say that it's OK to put #region tags in the middle of methods, so that you can then take that answer and show your co-workers, well, sorry, most of us don't seem to like the idea.)

Comment: Challenging an answer is not the same as completely disagreeing. Sometimes you need to push an idea a bit and see people defend it before you can truly understand it. I didn't challenge unit testing answer because I thought it was wrong, only because I wanted some elucidation about *how* useful being able to unit test each code chunk is so that I might better understand the costs and benefits involved in this type of decision. The best type of learning is interactive, in my mind, and you're doing yourself a disservice if you accept the teacher's answers without questioning them.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the example you give in your argument is less about YAGNI (You ain't gonna need it) and more about writing proper quality code that is easily maintainable.

In the earliest programming courses we learn that if a method is 700 LOC long, it is probably too big and certainly would be a giant pain to try and debug.

Secondly if I write methods A, B and C that are only used within method D, then I can more easily unit test A B and C independently of D, allowing for more robust unit tests in all 4 methods.

Comment: Unit testing is certainly a fair point, but I'm not sure it justifies pollution of the class scope in every case. Realistically speaking, does anyone actually unit test every little private method they write? I'd say people tend to unit test the private methods that get used a lot, that is to say, private methods which would be candidates for code-reuse anyway.

Comment: @jjoelson If the method has meaningful logic and isn't wrapping some other functionality then I always write a unit test against it. Unit testing methods has nothing to do with code reuse. You should unit test methods to verify that for given inputs that you get expected outputs in a consistent and repeatable manner. If you are noticing that the class scope is getting *polluted* as you call it, then perhaps your class is violating the Single Responsibility Principle.

Comment: Most programmers that I've met disagree with the idea of unit testing every private method. It's just not worth the time time it takes to implement and maintain tests on all private methods.

Answer (score 3):

> Suppose we have a method whose computation can be separated into three rather distinct phases. Furthermore, each of these stages is only relevant to the computation for this method, and so extracting them into new methods gains us no code reuse. What, then, are the benefits of extracting each phase into it's own method? As far as I can tell, all we gain is some readability and a separate variable scope for each phase (which will help prevent modifications of a particular phase from accidentally breaking another phase).

Those are two benefits.  But the important one, to me anyway, is *debuggability*.  If you have to trace through that code, it's a lot simpler to be able to Step Over two of the three sections and only trace into the one that you care about.  Refactoring into smaller methods allows this; region tags do not.

Comment: `ctrl-f10` - run to cursor

Answer (score 2):

My personal rule is that if a method is longer than one screen, say 40 lines, it is too long. If a class is longer than 500 lines, it is too big. I break these rules sometimes, occasionally even by a large multiple, but I generally regret it within the year.

Even a method that is 20 to 30 lines is getting a bit long in most cases. So I would say using regions in a method is usually a bad idea, simply because it would almost never make sense to collapse a region of 20 to 30 lines into multiple sub-regions.

Breaking down functions that are long by this definition has at least two benefits:

1. You get to put a name on what those sub-functions are doing, which clarifies your present thinking and simplifies the task of later maintainers.
2. Decomposing into smaller functions forces you to pass only the parameters those smaller functions need, so the scope of the data they require and modify is very clear. This assumes you aren't accessing and modifying object state in a hundred different leaf functions, which I would also discourage.

In my experience, these rules produce code that is easier to write without making common mistakes and can be understood and modified later without breaking subtle behaviors. It doesn't matter if the person who has to understand/modify the code is someone else, or myself after I have slept and forgotten everything.

So I would consider regions in methods to be a "code smell" indicating that unsustainable practices are being applied. As always, there *could* be exceptions, but they occur so infrequently that they almost aren't worth discussing.

Answer (score 2):

Here we go [again](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/64449/15464) ... There are [plenty of other topics here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/51307/15464) on programmers which have ended up in the same discussion.

You point out some very interesting arguments relating to short functions. It is not a popular statement, but [I am with you on this](http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/function-hell/). After having discussed it oft times before, it is my impression the discussion usually boils down to whether you primarily focus on proper encapsulation, or take test driven development to the max. These are the two main contenders in what seems to be turning out yet another holy war, and I'm afraid we are on the under powered side.

However ...

The solution in my opinion definitely isn't wrapping the 'phases' in regions. [Code folding is used to sweep code under the rug.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/the-problem-with-code-folding.html) Leave the code there as it is, it might remind you that you might want to refactor that at a later time! To relate it to an argument in your question: how will you be able to see an opportunity for code reuse if you don't see any code? Long segments of code should be exactly that, a thorn in the eye which makes you want to refactor it.

As an appropriate replacement for regions, I suggest using **code paragraphs** as Alex Papadimoulis names them [in a comment](http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/function-hell/). You might actually already be using a similar approach. It are simply blocks of code with a comment header, explaining what the entire block does. You have the readability of functions, but are able to use normally spaced english sentences, and you don't lose any encapsulation.

Comment: Well I essentially use regions in order to delimit code paragraphs (regions can have comments which are visible even when the code is folded). I like using regions for this because it gives the maintainer the choice to see the code if she wants to examine the implementation or to fold it if she only wants to see the "big picture."

Answer (score 1):

Although I agree that usually it's better to refactor code than to use `#region`, it's not always possible.

To support that statement, let me give an example.

```
class Foo : IComparable
{
  private String name;
  private int foo;
  private Bar bar;

  public int CompareTo(Foo other)
  {
#region Ascending on name
     if (this.name < other.name) return -1;
     if (this.name > other.name) return 1;
#endregion
#region Usual order on bar
     int compBar = bar.compareTo(other.bar);
     if (compBar != 0) return compBar;
#endregion
#region Descending on foo
     if (this.foo > other.foo) return -1;
     if (this.foo < other.foo) return 1;
#endregion
     return 0; // equal
  }
```

It's easy to readjust the regions to alter the order, or to extend when addional fields are added to the class. Comments are required anyway to quickly see how the ordering is supposed to work. And most of all: I don't see how refactoring will help readability in this case.

However, those exceptions are rare. Usually it is possible to refactor, like many of the other answers say.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a single answer for why certain people or teams decide not to use `#region` but if I had to list a few this would be the top reasons that I've seen.

- The names and order of the regions make more explicit the ordering and organization of code which enforces a particular style which can become a source of contention and bikeshedding.
- Most concepts don't cleanly fit into a small number of regions. Typically you start with regions by access modifiers **public**, **private** then maybe by member type (ex. method, property, field) but then what about constructors that span those modifiers, static varieties of all of these, protected members, internal members, protected internal members, implicit interface members, events, etc. In the end you would have most well designed classes where you have a single or method in each region due to the granular categorization.
- If you are able to keep pragmatic and only group things into a say three or four constistent types of regions then that may work but what value does it really add? If you are designing classes well you really shouldn't need to sift through pages of code.
- As hinted above regions can hide ugly code which may make it seem less problematic than it is. Keeping it as an eye sore may aid in getting it addressed.